# downloaded Image creating problem in html

Tags: html, css, image

I created a website using html and css , in which i used images direct from internet by coping image adders and some images i downloaded . The image that I copied from internet is showing on both desktop and mobile but the images that I have downloaded is showing only in computer not in mobile or tablet. I don't know what the problem is . Pls help me .

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Right-click download your image. Or if you have Firefox/Chrome do an inspect. Believe you are facing a localhost or file:// reference to the image.

Comment: It would also help if you start sharing what source codes you have. A good way to ask your question.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Location of your image matters a lot. The image should be in website folder.

Have you created a folder like "images" in your website directory?

If not, then please do this change and secondly,

after doing the above thing, the url of the image in the code should be like "/images/image-name.jpg". change extension according to the image.